# Removing / hiding the "collapser" of an <af:panelSplitter>

Tags: xml, panel, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm working on an Oracle ADF Fusion project using JDeveloper 12c (12.2.1.4.0). When I had to do some changes on several jsf pages I came to this tiny problem that I didn't find a way to get rid of that "collapser" button that seems to get implemented automatically whenever i use an `<af:panelSplitter>` no matter of the splitter position (see yellow spots and ignore the clumsy censoring).

[image: Screenshot with yellow marked collapsers and a lot of clumsy paint]

I looked up for the [documentation of the <af:panelsplitter>](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48682_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_panelSplitter.html) but the only thing I found was the attribute `collapsed`. Trying to set that to `false` manually (and not use the setting `default (false)`) didn't get me rid of them. Is there maybe a parameter I can add to the xml source of the jsf page that's not mentioned in the documentation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us your exact JDev version, please?

User the 'disabled' property of the `<af:panelSplitter>`. This will hide the icon.

Comment: Exact version is 12.2.1.4.0. Setting disabled to true works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try adding the attribute "positionedFromEnd="true"" as indicated in the docs ?.

(collapsed="true")  && (positionedFromEnd="false"), the first pane is hidden such that the second pane stretches

(collapsed="true")  &&
(positionedFromEnd="true"), collapsing the splitter hides the second pane.

Hope it works, best.!